# .NET Create Application-level ImageList without localization

Tags: c#, .net, localization, imagelist

I found several questions about how to avoid ImageList localization in .Net, but no one has answer.

One topic was found here http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/imagelists-localized-forms-t1322098.html, but it's realy old, maybe this problem has a solution today?

Comment: Do not use `ImageList` in winforms at all. Generate list and assign images programmatically. You don't really need to see in designer how you form looks in runtime. Other thing... do not use default localization (that ms satellite assemblies bullshit), make own.

Comment: @Sinatr, Both things are right. But I am just interested if there are any solution for this problem.

Comment: What solution? If you use `ImageList` in form and that form is localizable, then it will get copied and you have to localize it individually. This is intended behavior and it is not a bug (it's by desing). If you don't like it, then simply don't use it.

Comment: I didn't say it is a bug. My question about behavior - maybe it is possible to disable localization on any control.

Comment: Disable by removing it from the designer.

Comment: Well. It is a solution. But then it is not possible to use Designer dialogs :D